# Что за странная метка [sql-linq]?

Tags: обсуждение, метки, использование-метки

[sql-linq](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-linq)

Что это такое и нужно ли это нам?

Нужно ли это синонимизировать с [linq2sql](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linq2sql) или удалить вовсе?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Такой вещи как sql-linq не существует, поэтому метку стоит удалить.

Answer (score 3):

Вопросов по этой метке всего шесть и большинство авторов использует эту метку как синоним для linq2sql.

А вот первый автор смог внести неясности в эту стройную картину ;) он явно имеет ввиду провайдер для linq2sql.

Есть два варианта, что делать.

Простой: синонимизируем. Это быстро и просто, а главное - раз у нас де факто никто не видит разницы между этими метками, то и не надо. (Но вот если придут умные и разборчивые... да и вообще: просто - не значит правильно)

Сложный: оставляем как есть, но убираем с метки вопросы, которые к ней не относятся. Это способ правильный, не намного сложнее, ну а что на метке один вопрос останется - пусть будет открыто для будущих участников.

Плохо то, что насыпят ведь опять вопросов из Linq2sql. :( И то, что мы описание правильное навесим на эту метку поможет, но не особо - описания к меткам не часто читают.

Comment: Оба варианта мне не особо нравятся, поэтому не хочу ничего решать ---, хочу туфельки и купальник---.

Answer (score 1):

Удалил данную метку, так как за 7 лет 6 вопросов — недостаточное основание для того, чтобы метку делать синонимом. Возможно, данное действие будет иметь смысл, если данную метку воскрешат, в чём я не уверен.

Все 6 вопросов по-максимуму отредактировал, а не только вырезал данную метку.

Comment: Вчера было около двадцати, кто-то проредил еще вчера :)

Answer (score 0):

Ответ кроется в [первом вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/4472/sqlite-%D0%B8-linq), заданном с этой меткой.

Comment: И что это за ответ?

Comment: @АндрейNOP связка для sqlite и .net linq

Comment: Провайдер для Linq2Sql или для EF? И что делать с этой меткой?

Comment: @АндрейNOP можно спросить у автора упомянутого вопроса :-D